# logic apps web hook to chalkboard API timeout error

Tags: timeout, webhooks, azure-logic-apps

How do I change the timeout duration in logic apps web hook and also in chalkboard API.

The error message I get is.

> "message": "Http request failed: the server did not respond within the timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at [https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits"](https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [Perform long-running tasks with the webhook action pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app#perform-long-running-tasks-with-the-webhook-action-pattern).

[image]

After understanding the webhook pattern, you need to design some code, you can refer to the following sample:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Http;
using System;

namespace HttpToQueueWebhook
{
    public static class HttpTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("HttpTrigger")]
        public static IActionResult Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")]HttpRequest req, 
            TraceWriter log,
            [Queue("process")]out ProcessRequest process)
        {
            log.Info("Webhook request from Logic Apps received.");

            string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            string callbackUrl = data?.callbackUrl;

            //This will drop a message in a queue that QueueTrigger will pick up
            process = new ProcessRequest { callbackUrl = callbackUrl, data = "some data" };
            return new AcceptedResult();
        }

        public static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        /// <summary>
        /// Queue trigger function to pick up item and do long work. Will then invoke
        /// the callback URL to have logic app continue
        /// </summary>
        [FunctionName("QueueTrigger")]
        public static void Run([QueueTrigger("process")]ProcessRequest item, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {item.data}");
            //Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
            //ProcessResponse result = new ProcessResponse { data = "some result data" };
            
            
            //handle your business here.
            
            
            client.PostAsJsonAsync<ProcessResponse>(item.callbackUrl, result);
        }
    }

    public class ProcessRequest
    {
        public string callbackUrl { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProcessResponse
    {
        public string data { get; set; }
    }

}
```

The above code will first save your `callbackUrl` and the passed data to the queue, and then return the result of 202 to the logic app.

The `QueueTrigger` function will be triggered, and you can handle your business here.

You can call your http function like this in Azure logic app:

[image]

This solution can help you solve the http timeout problem. For more details, you can refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/calling-long-running-functions-from-logic-apps-6d7ba5044701).